# Devo nodejs-sdk not sending data

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am doing an integration with [Devo](https://www.devo.com/) with its [node library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@devo/nodejs-sdk) from NPM.

I have followed the [steps defined in the documentation](https://github.com/DevoInc/nodejs-sdk/blob/master/docs/sender.md) and I don't receive any error but the messages are not received in the platform. Previously I tested the platform sending http requests and it worked right, I can see the data in the table.

```
const sender = Devo.sender({
        host,
        port,
        cert: Fs.readFileSync(cert),
        key: Fs.readFileSync(key),
        ca: undefined,
        tag: "my.app.XXXX.test",
        debug: true,
    })

sender.send(message, (error) => {
        if (error) {
            Log.e("Error sending devo message: " + error)
            return
        }

        Log.d("Sent OK")
    })
```

I am not sending CA because I read is not necessary but it is something I haven't tried yet.
I tried sending the port as string and as number.

The callback is never called.

AFTER SOME TRIES:

I have been trying to send without certificates and the callback is called without error. The problem is that it is not visible in Devo and it has sense because the certificate should be contain the domain. I don't know where is storing the sent data.

I have checked that the callback is not called when the certificate is used. If I use the private key and the CA the callback continue being called. The bad news are that the data is not visible in Devo yet.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for reaching us. We are working on a new release that will address this issue. If you want to move forward, feel free to use the following workaround in the meantime:

```js
const sender = devo.sender(...);
sender._socket.ref(); // add this line immediately after the previous one
sender.send(...);
```

After doing that, take into account that a call to `sender.end()` will be required in order to the process to stop.